# Best Ways to Do Database Operation's In android?

Tags: android, database

i am finishing my android Application and at The end i find out i have alot of insert, delete operations in the Sqlite Database ,now i have a content provider with a cursor Loader and i have a few Questions please :

1.Which one is best Way for DataBase Operations ? Sql raw Query, Insert From ContentResolver , Or Insert From SqliteDatabase Class ?

2. do i need to do these operations in BackGround (Considering there are Alot of Them, Which imo Causes the BG Operations have some Con's for Creating a Async Rapidly)
3. do i need to Load Cursor In BackGround While im Using LoaderManager?

Thanks Alot in Advance

Comment: ad 3 you can use AsyncQueryHandler if you need to,  ad 4 no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `ContentProvider` is only required if you plan to share data from your app to other apps.

Since you already implement a `ContentProvider`, you should be communicating your data with a `ContentResolver`.

For your second question, any CRUD operation should be done asynchronously. Here is a quote from the [Android developer page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#SimpleQuery):

> For the sake of clarity, the code snippets in this section call
>   ContentResolver.query() on the "UI thread"". In actual code, however,
>   you should do queries asynchronously on a separate thread. One way to
>   do this is to use the CursorLoader class, which is described in more
>   detail in the Loaders guide.

About your third question: let your `Activity` or `Fragment` implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>`, and in `LoaderCallbacks#onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)` you can instantiate your `Loader` safely in an asynchronous way.

Comment: well the first one is not true after introducing ContentProvider as best Resource for Loader Manager, But rest are true, Thanks alot